# How to edit a copy of full ToggleButton template in WPF? Some triggers missing

Tags: wpf

I'm confused about the proper way to edit a WPF control template in VS2017.

I want to change the ToggleButton template so that when it is checked a tick appears in the bottom corner.

So I created a ToggleButton, right-clicked it, then pressed Edit Template -> Edit a Copy... which resulted in the code below:

However this code is missing triggers for IsChecked! Also it seems to define colours that I imagine would be in System in the real template.

I had a search online and found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/togglebutton-syles-and-templates but it seems to be incorrect as it is the template for a combobox.

What is the correct template?

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio.

Select a togglebutton you have in xaml.

Find Properties > Miscellaneous > Template

Click the little square to the right

From the context menu, choose Convert to new resource.

Edit
Vs2022 is different. No little square in properties now.
If you select the control in you'd designer and right click.
You will find an entry on the context menu

On win10 you should get:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBEE6FD"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC4E5F6"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF245A83"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF838383"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought to look there. I hardly ever use the Properties pane.

Comment: @Andy Do you know why this results in a "different" `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: I don't know for sure but clearly blend is looking somewhere else for it's template. I guess the reason for the difference is this has not been changed to match the current templates.

Comment: I could not find the "little square" in VS 2022, but the posted XAML works fine.

Comment: Vs2022 is different. I'll update the ppst

Answer (score 1):

The template you have is the current correct template, with the colors correctly set. You must understand that the `ToggleButton` has remained unchanged since 2006, so it's styling hasn't been optimized, and it's triggers haven't been replaced by `VisualStateManager`, which is the current norm.

The ToggleButton as standard doesn't change it's appearance when checked, which is why there is no trigger for the 'IsChecked' property in the template, however you can easily add these like so

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" 
            Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" 
            Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" 
            TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="Black"/>
</Trigger>
```

It doesn't do exactly what you would want, which is easy enough to achieve, but gives you the idea of where to start.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. For me, the default behaviour of the toggle button is to go a light blue when checked. (Windows 10, .NET Framework 4.7.2)

Comment: Ah yes, this is an old hang-over from Windows XP where your would select a desktop 'theme' (with names like Luna or Aero etc). Those theme's would make the WPF system add/change additional visual state changes. If you want to control this from your code, you will need to add the trigger as per my answer